# How do you get a JSP request string in the servlet?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I am using the apache tomcat servlet API and I am trying to create a page which will print the contents of a spreadsheet. Due to the fact that I am going to be dealing with a large # of cells, I am trying to develop a servlet that will dynamically handle requests. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
               <td><%= request.getAttribute("A1") %></td>
               <td><%= request.getAttribute("B1") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><%= request.getAttribute("A2") %></td>
               <td><%= request.getAttribute("B2") %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

right now, my servlet looks like this:

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

public Hello() {}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

                MySpreadsheetIntegration mySpreadsheetIntegration = new MySpreadsheetIntegration();

            request.setAttribute("A1", mySpreadsheetIntegration.cellVal("A1"));
                request.setAttribute("A2", mySpreadsheetIntegration.cellVal("A2"));
                request.setAttribute("B1", mySpreadsheetIntegration.cellVal("B1"));
                request.setAttribute("B2", mySpreadsheetIntegration.cellVal("B2"));

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(request.getQueryString());

            }
        }
```

My question is: is there a way to get the request parameter in the servlet? (i'm not sure if request parameter is the right term I'm referring to the "a1" part of request.getAttribute("A1") ).

Comment: I can't understand your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really bad at phrasing these, my goal is to write the servlet so it can take any cell address and output the value at that cell so if I write request.getAttribute("Z15") in my jsp, the servlet will be able to respond with the value of the cell at z15. to do that I need to get the "Z15" part of the request, my question is how do I do that?

Comment: You're confused. The JSP doesn't call the servlet. The servlet stores things in request attributes, then lets the JSP generate HTML, and the JSP gets the attributes stored by the servlet in the request attributes. To get the value of a query parameter "cell" sent by the browser, you call `request.getParameter("cell")`

Comment: Oh thanks, you're right I was confused, I think I know how to proceed from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `request.getParameter("param")` in servlet to get request parameter